# How to put functions in jest globals?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jestjs

I am setting up jest and it is not finding window.I18n.t() because it's defined by sprockets (ruby on rails, independent of webpack). So I'd like to mock that method. Here is the error:

```
 FAIL  spec/javascript/sanity_test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 't' of undefined

      24 |
      25 | export const newOrderPreferenceObject = {
    > 26 |   label: window.I18n.t("some.path.in.localization"), default_value: "",
```

in package.json I can do this:

```
 "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "globals": { 
      "window": {
        "I18n": { "t": {} }
      }
    },
```

I change testEnvironment from `jsdom` to `node`, as well.

However, t() must be a function, not a data structure. So how do I put a function in `window` in jest test?

Comment: Do you have a jest `setupTests.js` file at the root of your `src` directory?

Comment: @DrewReese I followed this: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#globalsetup-string and that didn't work - the global name "winow" was not visible from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the circumstances of your project but here's how I setup and mock global objects in my projects.

I create a `setupTests.js` in the root `src` directory and mock them there.

setupTests.js

```
window.I18n = {
  t: jest.fn(),
}
```

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#srcsetuptestsjs-1

Comment: This probably works in most cases. In my case, an imported module was relying on window.I18n.t() function and I was unable to do the stub before import. So my solution was to not use `window` in that module, so I didn't really solve this one.